# Capturing TextChanged event from DataGridComboBoxColumn using Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, events, caliburn.micro

I'm having problems passing the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` part of a `ComboBox` to the associated view model.

As expected:

1. On `TextChanged` the `OnTextChanged()` method in the code behind is called.
2. On `KeyUp` the `OnKeyUp()` method in the view model is called.

However:

1. On `TextChanged` the `OnTextChanged()` method in the view model is not called.

Why is it not called and how can I fix it?

```
<UserControl x:Class="AutoComplete.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Code">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <EventSetter Event="TextBoxBase.TextChanged" Handler="OnTextChanged"/>
                            <Setter Property="cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext" Value="{Binding DataContext, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event TextBoxBase.TextChanged] = [Action OnTextChanged($source, $dataContext)]; [Event KeyUp] = [Action OnKeyUp()]"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Suggestions, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because Caliburn Micro by default uses the `EventTrigger` class for `Message.Attach`. According to [this post](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.se/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html) `EventTrigger` uses reflection to find the event using the `EventName` property which fails since the `ComboBox` does not expose an event called `TextBoxBase.TextChanged`. Neither does it expose a `TextChanged` event, it's the `TextChanged` bubbling up from the `TextBox` component of the `ComboBox` that is supposed to be caught.

The above post also provides an adaptable solution. First a new `RoutedEventTrigger` class is created:

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    public RoutedEvent RoutedEvent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var element = (AssociatedObject as Behavior as IAttachedObject)?.AssociatedObject as UIElement
                  ?? AssociatedObject as UIElement;

        element?.AddHandler(RoutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnRoutedEvent));
    }

    void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        OnEvent(args);
    }

    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return RoutedEvent.Name;
    }
}
```

Then Caliburn Micro is configured to use RoutedEventTrigger instead of EventTrigger if possible:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private RoutedEventTrigger CreateRoutedEventTrigger(DependencyObject target, string routedEvent)
    {
        var routedEvents = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents().ToDictionary(r => $"{r.OwnerType.Name}.{r.Name}");
        if (routedEvents.ContainsKey(routedEvent))
        {
            var trigger = new RoutedEventTrigger
            {
                RoutedEvent = routedEvents[routedEvent]
            };
            trigger.Attach(target);
            return trigger;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        var baseCreateTrigger = Parser.CreateTrigger;
        Parser.CreateTrigger = (target, triggerText) =>
        {
            var baseTrigger = baseCreateTrigger(target, triggerText);
            var baseEventTrigger = baseTrigger as EventTrigger;
            return CreateRoutedEventTrigger(target, baseEventTrigger?.EventName ?? "") ?? baseTrigger;
        };
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

After this setup bubbling RoutedEvents can be used.